Most elegant way to switch between if and while statement in python?
I have an input which is either True or False. And I want to say if its True check for a condition once and if its False check for the condition all the time.
So I thought about something like this:
input: bool

if input:
   if condition():
      fucntion()
else:
   while condition():
         function()

But is there a more elegant way?

while condition():
    function()
    if input:
        break

